# ERROR: Cannot load message class for...Are your messages built?

Tags: ros, opencv, cv-bridge, topic, messages

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi, i'm trying to use this simple program to acquire an image from a ROS node (in gray-scale), convert it via cv_bridge (in order to elaborate it through OpenCV), find the middle point of some stains at the image borders and publish this poins on a topic as ROS messages.
my code is the following:

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <image_transport/image_transport.h>
#include <cv_bridge/cv_bridge.h>
#include <sensor_msgs/image_encodings.h>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <vector>
#include "rd_ctrl/proc_data.h"
#include <cv.h>

using namespace std;
namespace enc = sensor_msgs::image_encodings;


rd_ctrl::proc_data points;

 ros::Publisher data_pub_; 

 static const char WINDOW[] = "Image window";

 int i;
 int accu=0, accr=0, accd=0,accl=0;
 int jd=0, jr=0, jl=0, ju=0, je=0;
 CvScalar scalarl,scalaru,scalard,scalarr;
 std::vector <int> l,d,r,u;

 int nu=0,nd=0,nl=0,nr=0;


 class ImageConverter
 {
 ros::NodeHandle nh_;
 image_transport::ImageTransport it_;
 image_transport::Subscriber image_sub_;
 image_transport::Publisher image_pub_;
 public:
 ImageConverter()
 : it_(nh_)
 {
  image_pub_ = it_.advertise("out", 1);
 image_sub_ = it_.subscribe("/vrep/visionSensorData", 1,...
 &ImageConverter::imageCb, this);

 cv::namedWindow(WINDOW);
 }

  ~ImageConverter()
 {
 cv::destroyWindow(WINDOW);
 }

 void imageCb(const sensor_msgs::ImageConstPtr& msg)
 {
  cv_bridge::CvImagePtr cv_ptr;
 try
{
  cv_ptr = cv_bridge::toCvCopy(msg, enc::BGR8);
}
catch (cv_bridge::Exception& e)
{
  ROS_ERROR("cv_bridge exception: %s", e.what());
  return;
 }

 CvMat frame= cv_ptr->image;
cvSmooth(&frame, &frame, CV_MEDIAN);
cvThreshold(&frame, &frame,200, 255,CV_THRESH_BINARY);

//boundaries scanner

//left side (1)
for(i=0;i<256;i++){

 scalarl = cvGet2D(&frame, 0, i);
if(scalarl.val[0]==0) accl++;
if((scalarl.val[0]==255)&&(accl!=0)){
 l[jl]=(i-1-accl)/2;
 jl++;
 accl=0;
 nl=1;
 }
 if((i=255)&&(accl!=0)){ 
  l[jl]=(255-accl)/2;
 nl=1;
 }

 //right side (3)
 ...
 //up side (4)
 ...

 //down side (2)
 ...

  }
  cv::imshow(WINDOW, cv_ptr->image);
  cv::waitKey(3);

  image_pub_.publish(cv_ptr->toImageMsg());
  }
  };

  int main(int argc, char** argv)
  {
  ros::init(argc, argv, "image_proc");
  ImageConverter ic;

  ros::NodeHandle n;
  data_pub_ = n.advertise<rd_ctrl::proc_data>("/data_im", 1);

  points.u=u;
  points.d=d;
  points.l=l;
  points.r=r;
  data_pub_.publish(points);

  ros::spin();
  return 0;
   }
```

it compiles and runs but no messages are published (the above error occurs).
what could be the problem?
thanks for your time!!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/57103/error:-cannot-load-message-class-for...are-your-messages-built?/) by [mateo_7_7](https://answers.ros.org/users/4299/mateo_7_7/) on ROS Answers with karma: 90 on 2013-03-05

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Miquel Massot](https://answers.ros.org/users/2515/miquel-massot/) on 2013-03-05**:
I see you are advertising rd_ctrl::proc_data which I don't know its type. Can you post the entire error in your question? Maybe the problem is in that advertisement.

**Comment by [Asfandyar Ashraf Malik](https://answers.ros.org/users/5044/asfandyar-ashraf-malik/) on 2013-07-10**:
Hey, Did you figure out how to fix this problem.

**Comment by [Miquel Massot](https://answers.ros.org/users/2515/miquel-massot/) on 2013-07-12**:
Remove the line containing
" data_pub_ = n.advertise<rd_ctrl::proc_data>("/data_im", 1); "
and try again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

From a brief look at your code. Your problem is that you are publishing only once immediately. If the topic communications have not been setup yet in the background your single publish will likely get dropped.  Especially since you are publishing immediately at startup.

I suggest that you try publishing your data repeatedly like in the talker listener tutorials. http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber%28c%2B%2B%29

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-12-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0